# using namespace with array_map()

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, array-map

In a PHP web project, with two subfolders within the classes folder as follows:

project\classes\app

project\classes\utility

there is a class called Cleanse in the utility subfolder.  Here is a copy of part of the code in that class:

```
namespace classes\utility;

class Cleanse
{
    # ATTRIBUTES
    protected static $_ns = __NAMESPACE__;   

    # METHODS
    public static function escape($values)
    {
        return is_array($values) ?
                    array_map(self::$_ns.'\Cleanse::escape', $values) :
                    htmlentities($values, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }           
}
```

I am wondering if $_ns should be declared as static or not.  Is there a better way to declare this attribute and if so, how can it be called from within functions of this class?

Comment: Why do you need _ns property? Use `__NAMESPACE__` constant directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why are you putting the value of the php magic static **NAMESPACE** into your own variable? Why not just use **NAMESPACE** directly?

Otherwise, you can use private so only this class can access that variable and use it as 
$this->_ns, But realistically, i would just use the **NAMESPACE** variable itself.

If you do decide to declare it statically, use self::_ns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution, just use `array_map([static::class, 'escape'], $values)` instead of `__NAMESPACE__`:

```
class Cleanse
{ 
    public static function escape($values)
    {
        return is_array($values) ?
                    array_map([static::class, 'escape'], $values) :
                    htmlentities($values, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }           
}
```

Comment: Is there a name for this approach?  Unfortunately, it wouldn't work for me due to running an older version of PHP (5.4.4).  However, once upgraded I'll give this a try.  In the meantime, replacing `static::class` with `get_called_class()` worked.